# In how many ways can he send invitation cards?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations

A gentlemen has 6 friends to invite. In how many ways can he send invitation cards to them, if he has three servants to carry the card?

Now the first servant can go to any of friends so therese are 6 ways and for second servant there are 5 ways and for third there are four. So total number of ways are 6.5.4=120 but textbook states answer to be 729

Comment: By your method you're inviting only 3 friends

Comment: A particular servant can carry from $0$ to $6$ distinguishable invitations, and each of the particular invitations must be carried by exactly one of the $3$ distinguishable servants

Comment: If you also allowed the order of delivery by each servant into the calculation, you might get up to $\frac{8!}{2}=20160$ ways. More if you included order of receipt.

Comment: @kingW3 Ah i see thanks

Comment: On the other hand if you did not distinguish the servants or the recipients, and required each servant to deliver something, there might only be $3$ ways: $4+1+1, 3+2+1, 2+2+2$

Comment: @Henry these are partitions of 6

Answer (score 1):

For each friend assign a number from $1,3$ depending on which servant invited him you'll get $3^6=729$

Comment: This would allow a single servant to invite all 6 guests, which is not allowed...

Comment: @Bemte: What says this is not allowed?

Comment: @Henry I was sure that it said before that a servant can only carry three cards at most... Maybe it got edited out or I just misread, sorry.